# How can I execute and export in a single shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, source

I have two shell scripts.

```
$ cat java_alternative_7
#!/bin/sh
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle

$ cat java_home_7
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

It's simple that I can execute/source these two files.

```
$ sh java_alternative_7
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.x_yy

$ source java_home_7
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

How can I do these two steps in a single shot?

Comment: Why don't you merge the together?

Comment: @cuonglm I originally didn't know how to merge `sh` and `source`.

Comment: I mean move `export` command to the first script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to merge the scripts, as in

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sudo \
    env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle \
    update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

you may use

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sudo \
    env BASH_ENV=path/to/java_home_7 \
    bash -c 'update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle'
```

This would cause the script to run `update-java-alternatives` in a `bash -c`  in-line script started from `env` with `sudo`.  The `env` utility sets the `BASH_ENV` environment variable to the pathname of the script that sets the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.  This causes the `bash -c` script to automatically source the other script before it calls the `update-java-alternatives` utility.

The use of `env` to set the environment variables makes sure that the variables are set even though `sudo` may initially clear the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm aware of what I'm doing. Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
$ cat java7
#!/bin/sh
alternative=java-7-oracle
sudo update-java-alternatives -s $alternative
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/$alternative

$ cat java8
#!/bin/sh
alternative=java-8-oracle
sudo update-java-alternatives -s $alternative
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/$alternative

$ . java7;javac -version;echo $JAVA_HOME
javac 1.7.x_yy
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

$ . java8;javac -version;echo $JAVA_HOME
javac 1.8.x_yy
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

**UPDATE**

I'm updating for myself and anyone who needs.

First I added following line to my `~/.bashrc`.

```
#http://serverfault.com/a/276221/113357
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

And my new `~/bin/java_home` scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo please select a jname.
    update-java-alternatives -l
    return;
fi
jname=$1
sudo update-java-alternatives -s $jname
source ~/.bashrc
```

And when I want to change the JDK, I do.

```
$ source java_home java-7-oracle
$ source java_home java-8-oracle
```

The `JAVA_HOME` variable changes even in any new terminals. Previous `java7` and `java8` changed like this.

```
$ echo java7
#!/bin/sh
source java_home java-7-oracle

$ echo java8
#!/bin/sh
source java_home java-8-oracle

$
```

Comment: I take it you're using a Debian derivative. `update-java-alternatives` changes the `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` symlink to point to the selected JVM, so you can set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` once and for all. To switch JVMs you only need to run `update-java-alternatives` as appropriate, you don't need to change `JAVA_HOME`...

Comment: Or just set JAVA_HOME and stop screwing with the system level alternatives. (which a non-priv user cannot do.)

Comment: I installed `oracle-java7-installer` and `oracle-java8-installer` via `ppa:webupd8team/java`. There is no `default-java` in `/usr/lib/jvm/`.